# mysql array insert for repeat fields array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this PHP code to insert into mysql.

```
require_once("../form/corefile/functions.php");
$fn = new Functions();
$offers = $_REQUEST;
$offer=$_REQUEST['offer'];
$website =$_REQUEST['website'];
$keyword =$_REQUEST['keyword'];


$count_offer = count($_REQUEST['offer']);
var_dump($offer);exit;

for($i=0;$i<$count_offer ;$i++){
    $_offer  = ($offer[$i]);       
    $_website  = ($website[$i]);
    $_keyword  = ($offer[$i]);

    $query = $fn->InsertQuery("INSERT INTO offers (offer, website, keyword) VALUES ('$_offer','$_website','$_keyword')");
    //var_dump($query);exit;
    if($query)
{
$msg="Data Successfully Saved";
}

}
```

The array with `var_dump($offer)` looks like this;

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'offer1' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'offer2' (length=6)
```

I am getting the error:
`Notice: Array to string conversion in repeat.php on line 19`
where line 19 is the `$query = $fn->insertQuery`

Looks like I am making some mistake in pulling the correct data from the array.

Comment: `$_offer` is an array. What you probably need is `$_offer['name']`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - You are spot on. But  can you give me some idea how I should build the sql query with like `$_offer['name']` will that be correct. As doing this I am still getting the error - `Array to string conversion`

Comment: `{$_offer['name']}` should work. Or you assign `$_offer  = $offer[$i]['name']`. But best way would be to use prepared statements with parameter binding. Your code is open to sql injections.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - I will escape that with `mysqli_escape_string` or `addslashes`. I have not mentioned it compact the question.  Thank you for pointing out though. I should have included that in the question.

Comment: Don't use `addslashes()`! `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is the minimum you should do. And you could still forget to sanitize numerics. Using prepared statements you would have less to worry about.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Thanks for your suggestion and help. Now the query is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The array $offer is an array of associative arrays.$offer[0] would return an array of singular key value pair which ofcourse is not a String hence the error.